# laravel 5.5 returns array of stdObj from DB::select(DB::raw(""));

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have this query:

```
$models = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT
                Count(collected_items.id) AS total_collected,

                       ///some stuff

                FROM   collected_items

                      ///some inner joins

                WHERE  
                      ///Some clauses

                GROUP  BY collected_items.clause"));
```

in laravel 5.5 the query builder is returning an array of objects.
Now I can't loop into the resulting $models. Error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

```
    foreach($models as &$model){

        $model['picture'] = '/images/models/' . $model['picture'];
    }
```

How do you get an array of associative arrays instead? I was previously using the setFetchMode to get it but this can't be done anymore (easily) so I removed that and now I am fetching objects. I was also able to restore functionality by adding `$model = get_object_vars($model);` in the loop:

```
    foreach($models as &$model){
        $model = get_object_vars($model);
        $model['picture'] = '/images/models/' . $model['picture'];
    }
```

However I am wondering if that's the right thing to do or if there's a better way to get an array of associative arrays out of the query directly, using eloquent...

---

### update

result of:

```
    foreach($models as $i){

        print_r($i);
    }
```

is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total_collected] => 10
    [data] => data
    [id] => 218
    //...
)
```

result of `dd($models)` is:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#327
    +"total_collected": 10
    +"data": "data"
    +"id": 218
    //...
  }
]
```

so the result seems to be an array of objects.

Trying to add `->get();` at the end of the query results in error:

`Call to a member function get() on array`

Comment: `->toArray()`https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays

Comment: Already tried. Doesn’t work. It spits out an error. I can’t remember what now.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't return an array, a have a similar query: https://i.imgur.com/nDFgIQg.png

Comment: It returns stdObj . This is laravel 5.5 what yours ?

Comment: Mine is 5.5.Can you die dump it and post the results... `dd($models);`

Comment: Not at the moment. I’ll be back on Sunday.

Comment: However trying to loop into the $models the error is “Cannot use object of type stdClass as array”. It is probably returning an array of objects.

Comment: Did you tried to add `->get()` on the end of the statement? It should get collection not Query Builder model

Comment: No I didn’t. I’ll try

Comment: I updated the question with results of dd() and loops. It's an array of objects. the get() method throws an error as it's not available on an array.

Comment: Please check updated question with some more relevant information

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Eloquent really wants you to use the object syntax:

```
 $i->total_collected;
```

rather than use the array. Your use of get_object_vars() is the way I resolve this when I want to use an array... and I have never found any "standard" reason why this is not OK, or another best practice of the right way to approach this. So you can do

```
$this_row_array = get_object_vars($i);
$this_row_array['total_collected'];
```

and that is totally legit as far as I am aware.

This is the type of answer that is likely to be eclipsed as Eloquent gets smarter, but given that your question is targeted to 5.5, I think you already have the right answer.

HTH,

-FT